# How to use a file to load data into database in Django

Tags: python, database, django

Hi I am new learner of Django and would like to figure out how to load some data into the database using a file(.py).

There are three tables in the database.

```
class region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50, null=False)


class country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=40, null=False)
    region = models.ForeignKey(region)

class office(models.Model):
    office_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    postal_code = models.IntegerField(null = False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(country)
```

Initially I use the python shell of enter some simple data into the db using

```
>>> r = region(region_name='asia')
>>> r.save()
```

Can anyone help to create such a file to load data of region, country, office into the database? as there are sets of region,country,office that really need to be there.

Thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: Which database are you using? Generally the bulk loading tools that come with the database are a better way to load data in than writing your own.

Comment: @hd1 postgres, yea now I see should use the fixture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide initial data to your models by using fixtures. For that, you can store all data in a file named initial_data.xml (or yaml/json] file in the fixtures directory of your app. You can see the [django reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) for details